# React routing with backend routing

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-router

I have a React app with php on backend.
I have the APIs on backend side, like `example.com/api/***`

I use react-router-dom for routing on frontend side:

```
const App = () => { return (
    <div>
          <BrowserRouter>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/about' component={AboutComponent}/>
                <Route exact path='/' component={RootComponent}/>
              </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
)}
```

when i try to go to `example.com/api/myAPIMethod`, the route is handled by React, and React renders blank page, but i need to get it handled by my php backend.

the question is: how can i go to my `example.com/api/myAPIMethod` manually through  my browser's address bar. I wish to handle only this method through my php framework, other methods will be used through axios or fetch

Comment: If route/url handler at the server side returns the `index.html`, then you'll see that blank page rendered by `react`. I'm guessing your server does not differentiate between `/api/blah` and `/blah`. You need to look into that. If you need more help, update your question to include what web server you're using as well as server side router code.

Comment: on the server side i use slim php framework with nginx. i have some routes there: '/' route renders index.html with react inside, and other routes on '/api/***'. When i use blank index.html page without react, my api methods are available through browser address bar, but they don't, when i use index.html with react inside

Comment: How do you go to `example.com/api/myAPIMethod`? Do you have a link on the page you click on or do you type it in your browser address bar?

Comment: manually type in the address bar

Comment: Then your server rules are wrong. Either the php routes or nginx handlers.